# "Invalid cross-thread access" in XAML when adding Toolkit components to Maps

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, expression-blend

I have the following piece of XAML code in my Phone Application Page:

```
    <maps:Map x:Name="BigMap" Pitch="53" LandmarksEnabled="True" PedestrianFeaturesEnabled="True" ZoomLevel="12" CartographicMode="Hybrid">
        <Toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
            <Toolkit:UserLocationMarker x:Name="LocationMarker" GeoCoordinate="{Binding Center, ElementName=BigMap}" />
        </Toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
    </maps:Map>
```

The point is that Visual Studio Designer and Blend show an `Invalid cross-thread access` error on that code. This makes impossible to edit element's properties through Properties window.

Although the program doesn't throw any exception while executing, and it executes fine, I find this situation a little bit annoying, because I have to type properties manually in XAML and cannot take advantage of the designer view.

How could I solve this problem?

I attach following image in order to better illustrate the problem:

[image]

Comment: Have you applied the relatively recent update 2 to VS2012? I found the VS designer to be much better behaved after that update.

Comment: Yes, I installed the update 2 when it came out.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue in XAML but the app is running ...
so I figured up its VS13 bug, Unloadind and then loading the project (or close and open the project will fix that).